# Which browser to choose

Tags: chrome, firefox

Up until now I have been using Comodo Dragon, it is a Chromium based browser that according to the company, protects your privacy and gives you extra layers of security.

I am planning to reset my windows 10 in a few days and since I love it when I have minimum programs installed, I prefer to install only one browser (right now I've got Dragon, Firefox and Edge).

I want a browser that is secure so that my computer will be protected from any malicious sites (very important), private so that as less data as possible about me will be transmitted to other companies such as Google (less important). Privacy is less important to me so I'm not going to start using TOR or proxies or VPNS or what not, but it would still be nice not having my data/browsing habits transmitted to others.

From the research I've done on the internet and my own personal interests, these are my reason to use each browser:

1. Dragon - a Chromium based browser.

   - Pro: Security - very good. Uses all the security patches from Google + adds extra layers of security from Comodo, as the company says.
   - Pro: Chromium based browsers are very fast and secure and have a very good extension support as well
   - Privacy - not so sure. Chrome tracks user activities - who's to say Comodo doesn't do that too?
   - Con: eats a lot of RAM. Whatsapp web does not work (because it's not Chrome). Also another service that I use a lot doesn't work because Chrome/Chromium browsers don't support Silverlight anymore.
2. Firefox

   - Security - as far as I understand, it's good but not as good as Chrome or Chromium based browsers. Can anyone confirm?
     Something about not having a sandbox. (http://www.extremetech.com/computing/178587-firefox-is-still-the-least-secure-web-browser-falls-to-four-zero-day-exploits-at-pwn2own)
   - Pro: Privacy - very good. Again, as far as I understand, since Mozilla is a company devoted to user privacy they don't transmit your data to others.
   - Pro: lighter than Chrome. Supports Whatsapp web and that other service I'm using.
   - can't really find any cons. Maybe a bit less extension support.

To conclude, I am more in favor of starting to use Firefox, but I'm afraid because of the security issue. Comodo claims to use extra security measures like DNS and SSL which I'm not really sure what they are, but more security is always good, right? So it's important for me to know if indeed there is a problem of security with Firefox, otherwise I would just make the switch.

Also - perhaps there are extensions (to either browser, though maybe Firefox would be better) that would help me put my mind at ease.

Comment: Sorry [Is tool x versus tool y a fair question?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/69/is-tool-x-versus-tool-y-a-fair-question)

Comment: @JanDoggen This is not really a question of tool x versus tool y but rather, is it really true that Firefox lacks security and should that be a consideration that prevents me from using Firefox.

Comment: "Comodo claims to use extra security measures like DNS and SSL" - DNS is the way your computer or phone resolves a web address like google.com into an IP address like 74.125.22.105 which it can understand.  SSL is a way to securely browse the internet.  Neither of these things are exclusive to a browser in any way (literally every internet-connected device uses DNS and the vast majority of browsers support the secure HTTPS protocol), which makes me think that Comodo Dragon might not be as unusually secure as you think it is.

Comment: FYI, one of the reasons that Firefox isn't as RAM-hungry as Chrome is the way it deals with pages; with Chrome, each tab is a separate process, which allows better security (sandboxing) but also much more resources.  Firefox keeps everything in one process like most browsers, which is probably technically less secure but unlikely to make much of a difference unless you are *constantly* visiting sketchy sites.  It also doesn't gobble RAM.  My advice?  Pick whichever browser you prefer in terms of UI, install an ad blocker, and don't worry too much.  Everything major is reasonably secure.

Comment: @Eran Neither is this a feature discussion board, or are questions like "Does X have/lack feature Y" on-topic here. This site recommends software for specific requirements.

Comment: @WindowsEscapist thank you for your answers! Mentioning that Firefox is a bit less secure is somewhat of a concern but since it's only a little bit, I'll take it :). Any extensions that I can use to make it a little bit safer (privacy and security)?

Comment: @Eran there's always Ghostery (anti-tracking) or if you're really paranoid, NoScript.  Beyond that I don't know, but Firefox has an enormous library and I'm sure you can find some article with a list of good privacy and security-related extensions.

Comment: Note that Comodo also offers IceDragon, which is based on Firefox. That might solve the RAM issue.

Comment: @Timmy thanks, I know, but Whatsapp web doesn't work in IceDragon, so that's a problem.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend to use a mainstream browser if security is not that important, and only for sites where you really care use another one. Because when people are developing websites they normally always test it on the major browsers. Thus websites can look a bit weird if it uses something the browser does not support.

Answer (score 1):

I am using Maxthon(to get information and visit most sites), still am, its got an adblocker app built in with the installation. Firefox(actually using waterfox for videos) you can install noscript and it allows only whatever you want to view, blocks the others thus making it impossible for the other unwanted links to get information from you.

Comment: The OP asks about two specific browsers, not about what other browsers or plugins are available.